# AWS CLI Filter / Query Newbie Questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Pretty new to AWS CLI and --query and --filter. I've been training around with some commands I've found searching around. I have a few questions if anyone can assist that would be greatly appreciated.

1. I'm attempting to display a table of EC2 Instances and filtering results. How would I correctly retrieve hostname info in this query because when I do the following below, in the table the Hostname column shows "None":

```
aws ec2 describe-instances 
--query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Instance:InstanceId,PrivateIP:PrivateIpAddress,Type:InstanceType,Hostname:hostname|[0].Value,Status:State.Name}"  
--filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" "Name=tag:Name,Values='*'"  
--output table
```

1. Does AWS have a master list of "Identifiers" and what is needed to put on the other right side of the ":" (if I'm saying this correctly) and what I mean Identifiers is

```
Instance:InstanceId,PrivateIP:PrivateIpAddress,Type:InstanceType,etc".
```

As I would like to add more things to the table but I'm confused on
the syntax as I sometimes get a parse error COMMA or I get None for
that specific column like I am for Hostname.

Examples:

```
        - Instance: "what other options can I input here besides InstanceID"
        - Hostname: "what do I enter here to get the hostname info" 
        - Type: "what other options can I input here besides Instance"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Htgw.png

Answer (score 0):

The `Hostname:hostname|[0].Value` part in your command would be `Hostname:PublicIpAddress`. To check the item names, I just run `aws ec2 describe-instances` and see which name is used for the value we want.

It's rather complicated because [--filters option](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html#options) in `aws ec2 describe-instances` has its name syntax.